# datagridview column name C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

i am trying to set custom name for my column names in c# but when i load the form i dont get the names here is an example of my code:

```
        string Konekcija = "datasource=localhost;port=3309;username=root;password=1234";

        string Query = "select * from baza.artikli";

        MySqlConnection konn = new MySqlConnection(Konekcija);

        MySqlCommand komanda = new MySqlCommand(Query, konn);

        MySqlDataAdapter MyAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        MyAdapter.SelectCommand = komanda;
        DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
        MyAdapter.Fill(dTable);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dTable;


        dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = true;
        // имиња на header ите
        dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumnHeadersHeight();

        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "ид";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Баркод";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Назив";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "Набавна цена";
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "Продажна цена";
        dataGridView1.Columns[5].Name = "Данок";
        dataGridView1.Columns[6].Name = "Количина";
        dataGridView1.Columns[7].Name = "Опис";
        dataGridView1.Columns[8].Name = "Македонски производ";
        dataGridView1.Columns[9].Name = "Производител";




    }
```

Maybe i am missing something but i cant seem to find what it is so if you now please le me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
dataGridView1.Columns[index].HeaderText= "something";
```

Hope helps,